# Regular expression validation contain .com at the end of Email

Tags: regex, validation, email, email-validation

I am working on the Regular Expression validation and validate on the email textbox.
But the condition is use enter valid email but at the end of email use .com only i use this 
ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@abc.com$" it works but only for abc at the end of @ .
But i need that use will enter any number or alphabet after @ .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i need that user will enter any number or alphabet after @

```
ValidationExpression = "^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@[A-Za-z\d]+\.com$"
```

Comment: It should be noted, that while this perfectly satisfies the OP's requirement in the quote, it leaves a gap of valid emails. This would satisy for `@example1.com`, but not `@foo.example1.com`, or even `@foo-example1.com`

Comment: As I said. You will never get email validation right using regular expressions.

Comment: yep, correct,. for smaller cases, it would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should not validate email addresses using regular expressions. [You will most probably get it wrong](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

To validate whether a string ends with `.com`, use this regex:

```
\.com$
```

That's it. Example in C#:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(eMail, @"\.com$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

But then, in C#, you could just write

```
if (eMail.EndsWith(".com", StringComparson.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```